# Why do I have to make a 2d array for this

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, stl

I was solving a question online on strings where we had to perform run-length encoding on a given string, I wrote this function to achieve the answer

```
using namespace std;

string runLengthEncoding(string str) {
  vector <char> encString;
  int runLength = 1;
  for(int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
      if(str[i - 1] != str[i] || runLength == 9)
      {
        encString.push_back(to_string(runLength)[0]);
        encString.push_back(str[i - 1]);
        runLength = 0;
      }
      runLength++;
    }
  encString.push_back(to_string(runLength)[0]);
  encString.push_back(str[str.size() - 1]);

  string encodedString(encString.begin(), encString.end());
  
  return encodedString;
      
}
```

Here I was getting a very long error on this particular line in the for loop and outside it when I wrote:

```
encString.push_back(to_string(runLength));
```

which I later found out should be:

```
encString.push_back(to_string(runLength)[0]);
```

instead
I don't quite understand why I have to insert it as a 2D element(I don't know if that is the right way to say it, forgive me I am a beginner in this) when I am just trying to insert the integer...
In stupid terms - why do I gotta add [0] in this?

Comment: `to_string(runLength)` is a string. `to_string(runLength)[0]` is the first char of that string. encString is a vector<char>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::to_string()` returns a `std::string`. That's what it does, if you check your C++ textbook for a description of this C++ library function that's what you will read there.

```
encString.push_back( /* something */ )
```

Because `encString` is a `std::vector<char>`, it logically follows that the only thing can be `push_back()` into it is a `char`. Just a single `char`. C++ does not allow you to pass an entire `std::string` to a function that takes a single `char` parameter. C++ does not work this way, C++ allows only certain, specific conversions betweens different types, and this isn't one of them.

And that's why `encString.push_back(to_string(runLength));` does not work. The `[0]` operator returns the first `char` from the returned `std::string`. What a lucky coincidence! You get a `char` from that, the `push_back()` expects a single `char` value, and everyone lives happily ever after.

Also, it is important to note that you do not, do not "gotta add [0]". You could use `[1]`, if you have to add the 2nd character from the string, or any other character from the string, in the same manner. This explains the compilation error. Whether `[0]` is the right solution, or not, is something that you'll need to figure out separately. You wanted to know why this does not compile without the `[0]`, and that's the answer: `to_string()` returns  a `std::string` put you must `push_back()` a single `char` value, and using `[0]` makes it happen. Whether it's the right `char`, or not, that's a completely different question.

Comment: Thank you so much this cleared my doubts and some flaws in my conceptual understanding!